# AWS - 'Failed to get bucket name' when doing git aws.push

Tags: django, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate

I have a Django application and am using AWS servers to host the app. Before, I used to do

```
git add .
git commit -m 'made changes'
git aws.push
```

and it used to work perfectly fine. All of a sudden, I did it again after a few weeks and now it says

```
Error: Failed to get the Amazon S3 bucket name
```

. When I do

```
eb status
```

it says

```
routines: SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: certificate verify failed
```

Why is it giving me these errors when it used to work perfectly fine a few weeks ago? I never changed my IAM user's password. Does it change automatically? Because I still have the credentials file when I created the IAM user and the password in that file is the same password I am using.

Is there any error log where I can get further information to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's a trite answer, but I'd suggest updating `eb`. They've made some improvements to the API since I last updated earlier this week, and some changes to their architecture when it comes to Python apps (now defaulting to Python 3). Running `pip install awsebcli --upgrade` may do the trick, if Amazon have made potentially breaking changes, or the Boto library is out-of-date on your machine.